# may connect 26 pin touchscreen display to a 40 pin raspberry pi A+?

Tags: gpio, display, rpi.gpio, touchscreen

Recently, i've got as a present a raspberry pi a+ (40 GPIO pins) and touchscreen display for older version (26 GPIO pins)
I tried to google, but wherever i search it gives me description of the new A+ or says to pin everything in the correct order.
I wonder if i connect 26 pins screen to a 40 pins, ill it work or i shouldnt do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 26 pins on the 40 pin A+ expansion header have the same functionality as the first 26 pins on the standard A expansion header.

If your screen works on the A expansion header it should work on the A+ expansion header.

Why not post a link to the screen?

Comment: http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/6363488523.html

Comment: @Aziz That should be fine.  You may have a mechanical problem in fitting the socket over the A+'s pins.  It will probably be blocked by pins 27 and 28.  You have two choices (if it is blocked). 1) carefully file the blocked part of the socket so that it is no longer blocked. 2) very much a poor second choice, snip off pins 27/28, but that would mean that many future HAT boards (expansion header boards) may not work properly, and you would lose the second I2C bus (mind you it is meant to be reserved for system use).

Comment: Defenetely im not gonna cut the 27/28 pins, so if the lcd is not gonna fit there, i will have to sell it (not at home at the moment so i cannot check it now) :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @joan stated the first 26 pins on the A+  header have the same functionality as the first 26 pins on the standard B & B+, and except for the pins 3 & 5 (I²C) and pin 13 are the same as A.

It is unlikely the minor difference will be significant. Much software automatically detects the difference.

It certainly won't damage either the Pi or the display.

NOTE The physical layout of the pins differs, which may affect the position of the display if directly mounted on the Pi.

NOTE2 You can't use a 26 pin IDC cable and header for mechanical reasons.